# What should I do to prevent confusion for pilots due to the long distance between edge units on taxiways next to rapid exit taxiways?

Tags: airport-design, airport-lighting, taxiways

We are at Hurghada Int’l Airport (HEGN) and we have a problem in three rapid exit taxiways named V5, V6 and V7 with taxiway V:

[image: HEGN ground chart]

Moving to V5 for example, if you measure the distance between the first taxiway edge light unit on V before the entrance of V5 and the first edge unit on V after the exit of V5, it is 280 meters long. This may look like missing units to the pilots as you know the correct distance between edge taxiway lights is 60 meters.

So how can I solve that problem? For reference, we don’t have taxiway centerline lights, that’s why that problem occurred.

Comment: Could you add a bit more context to explain exactly what the problem is? Do you often get pilots making a wrong turn?

Comment: an issue with the longitudinal spacing of taxiway edge light units on main taxiway V at the intersection with rapid exit taxiways V5, V6, and V7. Since the standard spacing between taxiway edge light units is 60 meters, this presents a gap that exceeds the standard interval.

This issue has arisen because there are no centerline lights installed on the taxiway. The visibility level is not less than 550 meters, so centerline lights are not required. I don't recommend installing supplemental centerline lead-on lights on taxiway V in advance of the rapid exit taxiway intersections.

Comment: No any complains with pilots but it is an issue that should be fulfilled accordance to the aviation authority.

Comment: If no pilots are making mistakes here, I fail to see why this is an issue. If the aviation authorities require you to do something, surely they have explained to you exactly what needs to be done?

Comment: I would recommend you do some research using key words "problem statement".

Answer (score 0):

This is what you tell the aviation authority: The distance between any two edge taxiway lights is a multiple of 60 meters. The distance between any two *adjacent* edge taxiway lights is 60 meters, except where a light must be omitted due to interference with another ground feature, such as a crossing taxiway.

You could also say: Edge taxiway lights *when present* are spaced on a repeating interval of 60 meters. Some edge taxiway lights *may be omitted* from this sequence where they would interfere with other ground features, such as crossing taxiways etc.